# Outlier Detection in Meta-Analysis Models for Observational Studies of Adverse Drug Outcomes using Distributed Networks

Tags: simulation, outliers, meta-analysis, anomaly-detection

I hope you are in good health. My thesis is on outlier detection in meta-analysis models. I will be using a case study from Canadian Network for Observational Drug Effects Studies (CNODES) to detect outliers for robust prediction of drug safety and effectiveness.

CNODES is a distributed network consisting of seven Canadian provinces. Due to privacy legislation, each province estimate site-specific effect sizes and then combine all site-specific effect sizes to produce a pooled effect estimate using a meta-analysis. There are also other distributed networks around the globe (such as the Food and Drug Administration Sentinel Initiative by the United States, the Pharmacoepidemiological Research on Outcomes of Therapeutics by a European ConsorTium (PROTECT)) research on drug safety and effectiveness.
I have searched for outlier detection techniques used by these distributed networks but could not find one. My request to the colleagues is, please let me know if you are aware of any outlier detection techniques in meta-analysis models used by these other distributed networks.

If you find any papers/articles/reports around this, please do not hesitate to comment the link below the post. Thanks in advance for your time and help. I look forward to getting a response.

Comment: Software does implement leave-one-out methods to detect interesting observations.

Comment: I was going to recommend exactly what mdewey mentioned. In addition, you may start first by looking into heterogeneity testing (e.g. Q, Tau and I-squared statistics). Visual approaches like forest and funnel plots can also be helpful in identifying outliers.